# WPF UserControl overfilling parent window at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, resize

I'm setting up a WPF application where I have a header with radio buttons that change the view of the grid below it by changing the active UserControl. I also dynamically set the height and width of my window to be 80% of the height of the user's window. When the window displays my usercontrol, the Usercontrol either ends up overfilling the grid or the grid is cutting off the UserControl

I've set the row height to be dynamic and removed the default height and width for the usercontrol, but it continues to be cut off. From what I understand, the usercontrol should just automatically fill the size of the grid.

```
<Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill">
<Grid Height="880" Width="960">
        <!--Seperate View Style -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding }" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
```

```
            double FormatHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * .8;
            double FormatWidth = FormatHeight * 1.0909;
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Height = FormatHeight;
            this.Width = FormatWidth;
```

```
  <Grid Background="#EFEFEF" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border x:Name="AlertHelperPanel" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="White">
            <ListView Name="AlertNotifications" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=AlertHelperPanel}" 
                      Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=AlertHelperPanel}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Alerts}"
                      MouseDoubleClick="details_OnMouseDoubleClick">
                <ListView.View>
```

Comment: It's unclear what these XAML and code snippets are supposed to do and how they are related. What's the purpose of the Viewbox? When you say "user's window" do you mean the screen?

Comment: Thew viewbox is in place to handle different screen scalings. The grid below is where the contentcontrol for the usercontrols is defined, and the C# code below that is how I am setting the window size. Then the last piece of XAML below that is the usercontrol grid and how i defined it. Sorry I didn't make it very clear. By user window i was referring to the main window of my WPF program.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this issue was occurring because the usercontrols were scaling but expecting a specific aspect ratio. When the viewbox was removed the window size would adjust without changing the size of the controls inside, indicating to me it had to do with the usercontrol sizing versus window sizing. Adjusted my aspect ratios in the CS code until it was sized properly.